# iOS - `UIViews` behind `UICollectionViewCell`disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview

I have a gallery using `UICollectionView` that prepared using main.storyboard. I have a few `UIViews` and `UIButton` placed between `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewCell`. When I test the app, some of the `UIViews` and `UIButtons` disappear. 
[image]

But I have another catalog scene which prepared using the same way and everything is there. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Strange, I just drag an `UIView` behind all the missing views and delete it, everything show up again. Is this a bug? It did happen to me several times recently.

Comment: If you have solved your own problem, post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't mess with the UICollectionView's view hierarchy this way.  Since it handles its own list of subviews, yours may be obstructed.  I would suggest one of those two methods:

1. Set your UICollectionView background as `[UIColor clearColor]`, and put your own views *behind* that UICollectionView, in a hierarchy similar to this:

   - UIView

     - *Your Custom Views*
     - UICollectionView
2. Use the UICollectionView's `decoration views`.  You can read more about them [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html), in the "Including Decoration Views in Your Custom Layouts" section.

   > Decoration views are visual adornments that enhance the appearance of
   >   your collection view layouts. Unlike cells and supplementary views,
   >   decoration views provide visual content only and are thus independent
   >   of the data source. You can use them to provide custom backgrounds,
   >   fill in the spaces around cells, or even obscure cells if you want.
   >   Decoration views are defined and managed solely by the layout object
   >   and do not interact with the collection view’s data source object.